# Apache error message "Node not found"

Tags: apache-2.2

I was watching the error log of one of our servers and stumbled upon an error message which I haven't seen before:

```
[Wed Aug 03 15:19:29 2011] [error] [client **.**.**.**] Node not found
```

I can't find anything sensible using Google or on the Apache website or anywhere else either. Does anybody here know what that message is about?

I'm not running Tomcat or any other Java services. Just the vanilla apache with mod_php.

Answer (score 0):

How about a problem with XmlRpcRequest? Or any other XML related request/response from the application?

A probably not useful link for a similar problem: http://exist.2174344.n4.nabble.com/problem-Node-not-found-td2192249.html

Comment: I'm not running Tomcat or any other Java services. Just the vanilla apache with mod_php.

Comment: But you could have XML processing libraries in PHP that cause this.

Comment: I suppose, but the error is logged for every request and the app I'm running isn't parsing any XML at all. Or are you suggesting the error is caused by simply including the library?

Comment: No. I assumed that it has something to do with parsing XML. Loading a library does not produce the error. Then it must be something different I can't think of.